# Is it possible to Copy as CSV from Libreoffice Calc sheet?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, usability

Libreoffice Calc allows to "Save as" CSV, but it requires multiple steps to obtain the data  on clipboard, if the objective is to paste somewhere e.g. an LLM prompt.

Is there a quick way to right click selected cells and "Copy as CSV"? (with or without headers).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Likely not. The data is not *stored* as CSV inside the spreadsheet, since it has formatting, too. However, copied cells can be pasted directly into most applications as **tab** separated data. The clipboard is "smart" enough to "know" when to paste as text, or formatted.